# How to make class with const properties assignable?

Tags: c++, oop, constants

I have a simple point class:

```
class Point {
public:
    Point(const double, const double);
    /** This constructor creates invalid point instance **/
    Point();
    ~Point();
    const double x;
    const double y;
    /** This returns true if one of the values is NaN **/
    bool isInvalid() const;
    /** Returns true if coordinates are equal **/
    bool equal(const Point& p) const;
};
```

Values `x` and `y` are `const` so that I can be sure they never change. They are supposed to be always constant. The problem is I can't assign to variables holding `Point`:

```
Point somePoint;

  ... meanwhile, things happen ...

//ERROR:  use of deleted function 'Point& Point::operator=(const Point&)'
somePoint = Point(x, y);
```

I understand that assigning is a problem because `somePoint.x = something` is forbidden. I need to use point to hold last point value during rendering:

```
Point lastPoint;

PointInGraph* point = graphValues.last;

while((point = point->next())!=nullptr) {
  // calculate pixel positions for point 
  double x,y;
    ...

  if(!lastPoint.isInvalid())
    drawer.drawLine(round(lastPoint.x), round(lastPoint.y), round(x), round(y));
  // ERROR: use of deleted function 'Point& Point::operator=(const Point&)'
  lastPoint = Point(x, y);
}
```

So does `const` in class properties simply make any variable of that class type `const` as well? Or is there a workaround?

Comment: If you want to modify `x` and `y` at some point, why are they `const`? Maybe you just want them `private` and only changeable through the assignment operator? Or `lastPoint` could just be a pointer.

Comment: @TartanLlama I don't remember saying I want to modify them. I want to replace whole instance of the class, hence `point = Point( ... )`.

Comment: But the assignment means modification. It looks like you just want a raw pointer.

Comment: @TartanLlama I guess that if I was really evil, that would be the way to go.

Comment: Ah, I misread some stuff, @NathanOliver's solution looks like it'd work for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of making the variables `const` you could just not provide any way for the user to change the values by:

1. making them private
2. only allowing assignment to a another instance as the only way to change the values.

You can see how this would work in the following example:

```
#include <iostream>

class Point {
public:
    Point(const double x_ = 0, const double y_ = 0) : x(x_), y(y_) {}
    double getX() const { return x; }
    double getY() const { return y; }
private:
    double x;
    double y;
};

int main()
{
    Point a{1,5};
    Point p;
    p = a;
    std::cout << p.getX() << ", " << p.getY();  // no error here
    //p.x = 5; // error here now
    //p.y = 7; // error here now
}
```

<kbd>[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c2764059a2ba24f3)</kbd>

If you un-comment the last two lines you will get an error to prove that you cannot change `x` and `y`.

Comment: how do I do the second thing? Because that's what I'd like to do, replace the assignment operator to something that works.

Comment: @TomášZato You do not need to do anything if the variables are private.  The default assignment operator will work once they are non `const`.

Comment: I thought that's a list of options, not step by step solution. I guess that makes this post perfect argument to [those who are getting tired of seeing lists everywhere](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/307481/607407).

Answer (score 6):

It's not possible. It would require modifying `const` values.

Instead of making `x` and `y` themselves `const`, make them non-`const` but provide a `const` *interface* to them, i.e. by making them private and providing `const` getters.

Answer (score -3):

Actually it's, of course, possible by directly technique called **cast away constness** which is a known [loophole in `const` mechanic in C++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Const_%28computer_programming%29#Loopholes_to_const-correctness). Basically I can abuse the fact that `const int*` can be assigned to `int*` variable. The possible solution:

```
Point& Point::operator=(const Point& p)
{
  *((double*)&x)=p.x;
  *((double*)&y)=p.y;
}
```

This is of course **not recommended**, but I'm not the one of the people who think that knowledge is dangerous.

Comment: Casting away `const` on a `const` variable is undefined behavior.

Comment: Casting away `const` is fine, modifying the object after casting away `const` is undefined behaviour.

Comment: Can you come with a specific possible error that could arise from the code above? I mean, I knew I'm gonna get downvoted for posting this answer - ranks of purists on SO are endless - but I would actually like to hear something specific about this being wrong.

Comment: @TomášZato It's undefined behaviour, any error is possible.

Comment: It introduces undefined behavior.  That means anything can happen from your computer getting formatted to it working perfectly well.  You do not want to have undefined behavior in your code as it is a bomb just waiting to explode in your face.

Comment: Should I understand it so that it might damage the memory? I was always quite sure `const` exists for the programmer to mark what he doesn't want to change so that he doesn't "forget" (eg. due to complex code). But from your claims it means `const` has impact on the running program. What is it then?

Comment: @TomášZato: For one, it's fruitless to discuss about UB. It's UB, it's broken. But the `const` input to the function might conceivably reside in read-only memory (a ROM chip, BIOS, r-o hardware register, you name it). You can cast away the `const`, but that doesn't make the memory address writeable.